# What's an adjective to describe something "Of or relating to a row"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

Columnal: "Columnar"

[Columnar](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/columnar): "of, relating to, resembling, or characterized by columns"

[Tabular](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tabular): "of, relating to, or arranged in a table"

Comment: Well, "riotous" comes to mind, but that's probably not the sense you had in mind.

Comment: Suggest a sentence where you would use the adjective you are looking for. You may find useful:  ***In a row***, 
in a series without interruption They've won six games in a row.
http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+row

Comment: Perhaps "row-wise", to distinguish from "columnar"?  Still doesn't quite fit though...

Answer (score 2):

**Ordinal**:

> of or relating to a thing's position in a series

Source: Google "ordinal definition" I don't know what Google's source for definitions is.

Answer (score 1):

A row is basically a group of something arranged in a line. A row of houses. A row of seats. It rained for five days in a row.

Hence, a good word to describe something relating to a row would be **linear**.

Answer (score 0):

[***lateral***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lateral) -

> of or relating to the side

Seems so obvious in retrospect, but I spent an inordinate [pun] amount of time futzing through *parallel* and *translateral* before realizing that *lateral* is Latinate, from *lateralis*, as is *columnar* from *columnaris*.